# JSF Facelets with plain jQuery AJAX poll/push

Tags: jquery, jsf-2

In a JSF Facelets "web" application, is it possible to make a jQuery AJAX poll/push without the use of a component library (e.g. RichFaces/IceFaces/PrimeFaces)?

If jquery AJAX is used what should be used for the url = '' part?

Can I use the `#{BackingBean.property}`?

```
$.ajax({url:"demo_ajax_load.txt", success:function(result){
    $("div").html(result);
}});
```

Comment: b.t.w you know that you can invoke JSF ajax from within js code ? and in that case you wont need to use servlets... you will be able to call managed bean methods... and all this from your js...

Comment: *"without the use of a component library"* Surely.. Just write the same kind of code yourself as they did (in other words, reinvent the wheel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible the url should can be a servlet for example it should be

something like `/servlets/SomeServletName`

and in your web.xml add the mapping

like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SomeServletName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>your.package.name.SomeServletName</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SomeServletName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlets/SomeServletName</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

p.s backing bean property is not related in here...